# Command pattern in Swift with struct's mutating methods

Tags: swift, command-pattern

I am trying to understand how to implement the command pattern in Swift. So far, this code works fine:

```
class Subject
{
    var value: Int = 0

    func setValue(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Command<T>
{
    private var receiver: T
    private var instructions: T -> Void

    init(receiver: T, instructions: T -> Void) {
        self.receiver = receiver
        self.instructions = instructions
    }

    func execute() {
        instructions(receiver)
    }
}

var subject = Subject()

println(subject.value) // "0"

let instructions: Subject -> Void = { sub in Subject.setValue(sub)(2) }
let command = Command<Subject>(receiver: subject, instructions: instructions)
command.execute()

println(subject.value) // "2"
```

However, if I want the receiver to be a `struct` instead of a `class`, the same code doesn't work. So, if I define Subject as a `struct` as follows:

```
struct Subject
{
    var value: Int = 0

    mutating func setValue(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Then I get the error: "Subject is not convertible to inout Subject" on `let instructions: Subject -> Void = { sub in Subject.setValue(sub)(2) }`.

I don't know how to approach this. Any suggestion?

Comment: This could be difficult. Note that `self.receiver = receiver` in the Command init method already makes an *independent* copy of the struct.

Comment: So true... Which makes me think if I am having this problem due to bad design idea. Maybe it doesn't make much sense, in general, to apply the command pattern on a struct ("value") object(?) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you want to call a class method on an object you need to pass an inout parameter. This is done by appending a `&` in front of the variable:

```swift
Subject.setValue(&subject)(2)
```

However you can not do this from within an anonymous method, you need to type it as an inout parameter explicitly.

I do think that this code should work, however in my case it crashes Xcode playground and Xcode REPL:

```swift
struct Subject
{
    var value: Int = 0

    mutating func setValue(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Command<T>
{
    private var receiver: T
    private var instructions: inout T -> Void

    init(inout receiver: T, instructions: inout T -> Void) {
        self.receiver = receiver
        self.instructions = instructions
    }

    func execute() {
        instructions(&receiver)
    }
}

var subject = Subject()

println(subject.value) // "0"


var instructions: inout Subject -> Void = { sub in Subject.setValue(sub)(2) }
let command = Command<Subject>(receiver: &subject, instructions: instructions)
command.execute()

println(subject.value) // "2"
```